# undefined method `unread_messages' in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on the unread folder for my inbox messaging system. I received a undefined method `unread_messages' when going to /users/1/messages?mailbox=unread and it's pointing to the messages controller. However I have unread_messages defined in the user.rb so that it shows unread messages in the inbox, so I'm assuming the code should also work for the unread folder. Any help would be appreciated.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :role, :age, :age_end, :password_confirmation, :about_me, :feet, :inches, :password, :birthday, :career, :children, :education, :email, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :name, :password_digest, :politics, :religion, :sexuality, :user_drink, :user_smoke, :username, :zip_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, with: /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  has_many :galleries
  has_many :photos, :through => :galleries
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
  ROLES = %w[admin user guest banned]

  # models/user.rb
  after_create :setup_gallery

  def received_messages
      Message.received_by(self)
    end

 def unread_messages?
   unread_message_count > 0 ? true : false
 end

 def sent_messages
   Message.sent_by(self)
 end

 # Returns the number of unread messages for this user
 def unread_message_count
   eval 'messages.count(:conditions => ["recipient_id = ? AND read_at IS NULL", self.user_id])'
 end

  def to_s; username
  end

  def has_role?(role_name)
    role.present? && role.to_sym == role_name.to_sym
  end

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end

  private
  def setup_gallery
     self.galleries << Gallery.create
   end
end
```

messages_controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
    if params[:mailbox] == "unread"
    @messages = @user.unread_messages
  end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recipient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
   end

   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user.id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

message.rb:

```
attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recipient_deleted
validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"

belongs_to :sender,
:class_name => 'User',
:foreign_key => 'sender_id'
belongs_to :recipient,
:class_name => 'User',
:foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

# marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recipient, which ever the user that was passed is.
# When both sender and recipient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
     self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
     self.recipient_deleted = true if self.recipient_id == user_id
     (self.sender_deleted && self.recipient_deleted) ? self.destroy : self.save!
 end
# Read message and if it is read by recipient then mark it is read
def readingmessage
  self.read_at ||= Time.now
  save
end

# Based on if a message has been read by it's recipient returns true or false.
def read?
    self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
end

def self.received_by(user)
   where(:recipient_id => user.id)
 end

 def self.not_recipient_deleted
   where("recipient_deleted = ?", false)
 end

 def self.sent_by(user)
    Message.where(:sender_id => user.id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you've defined `unread_messages?` method, not `unread_messages`

Secondly, you should not use `? :` in `unread_messages?` method:

```
unread_messages_count > 0
```

is enough.

You should define `unread_messages` method in your User model. I can't show the inner code in this method because I don't know your models relations.

Comment: I have tried a few different def for it, can't seem to get the page to work. I included more code, including the messages model. If you could take a look and give some pointers that would be great. Also for the '?' in the unread_messages. What is the reason for not using it? I just want to understand removing it so I can know for future reference. Thanks

Comment: Include your User model source, please

Comment: Check this http://pastie.org/private/xemrvo3a3kz0xbevxker6a#15-28 (lines 15-28). I've added two relations, removed unnecessary code, and changed the `unread_messages?` method name to `has_unread_messages?`

Comment: If you do not understand my changes, please refer to some RoR tutorial and do not copy-n-paste code to your project without thinking.

Comment: @pwz2000 I've made a mistake in my pastie example. Line 19 should be like this one: `received_messages.count > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You defined

```
unread_messages? # note the question mark
```

Then referred to it as

```
@user.unread_messages # no question mark
```

You probably want a method

```
def unread_messages ## which holds the actual unread messages and does not return boolean
```